# Result of calling hci_inquiry

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, hci

When calling hci_inquiry how do I know/control if responses are of type inquiry_info,  inquiry_info_with_rssi or inquiry_info_with_rssi_and_pscan_mode?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the file `hci_lib.h`, in the prototype, the fifth argument is a double pointer to your `inquiry_info` array of size `num_rsp`.

```
int hci_inquiry(int dev_id, int len, int num_rsp, const uint8_t *lap, inquiry_info **ii, long flags);
```

`inquiry_info_with_rssi` and `inquiry_info_with_rssi_and_pscan_mode` are quite different structures so if you mistakenly use them you will have unexpected results.